# Generalized Inverse function in GSL

Tags: gsl, matrix-inverse

Is there any function to calculate Generalized inverse of a matrix using GSL?
Like in R, we have `ginv(X, tol = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It seems as if there is no routine to directly calculate the pseudo-inverse of a matrix (although [here](http://sourceware.org/ml/gsl-discuss/2008-q2/msg00013.html) you can find a discussion on how one could get it).

However, the explicit pseudo-inverse itself is seldom required. Instead, gsl provides the routine

```
int gsl_linalg_SV_solve (const gsl_matrix * U, const gsl_matrix * V, const gsl_vector * S
                       , const gsl_vector * b, gsl_vector * x)
```

see the documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Singular-Value-Decomposition.html#Singular-Value-Decomposition).

It solves the linear system `A x = b`, which is equivalent to applying the pseudo-inverse `A^+` onto `b` and yields `x = A^+ b`.

Before application, the SVD must be found via the routine `gsl_linalg_SV_decomp`. The tolerance factor `tol` you mentioned can be incorporated by looping over the singular values `S` and setting those smaller than `tol` to zero.

(Further, here is a personal suggestion: drop the gsl and switch to Eigen, armadillo, or comparable modern libraries)